# Why in flutter widgets child note accepting 'null' ? Is there any alternate?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
Expanded(
            child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: null),
              Expanded(child: null),
            ],
          )),
```

Here while I am using `child:null` it is showing error !!
why the error has appeared. is there any alternate to make an `Expanded` widget with child null ?

I have given `child:null` in flutter widget while it's not accepting, I have also tried giving `SizedBox()` it works fine but is there any other alternate for giving value null instead of `SizedBox()` ?

Comment: What do  you want  to build?

Answer (score 0):

I can transform your talk:

> is there any alternate to make an expaded widget with child null ?

what you're looking for then is no the `Expanded` widget, it is the `Spacer` widget, which gives you a widget that expands as max as possible in the area where it it put.

you can use it like :

```
Column(
   children: [ 
     Spacer(),
  ],
),
```

[Spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)

Comment: Thank you so much is using Expanded will be removed in future update ??

Comment: no no don't get it wrong, the Expanded widget is made so it takes a child and apply expanadation to it, so as example if you have a Container widget that should takes the whole space in a Column, you will need Expanded

Comment: but when  you do need something to expand without set a child as you mentioned, you're talking here about making a space between two things as max possible which is Spacer widget

Comment: both have their own use, and both are useful for their cases

Comment: I got it !! Spacer() does not need any child just expands the containers !!